# Recursive algorithm for substrings of the same character in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to build a **recursive** algorithm that, starting from a string such as "xxxzzppp", will only return true if every sequence (continous substring) of the same character is made up of less or equals characters compared to the following one, up to the end.

It is assumed that a string is alphabetically ordered.

It will return `0` otherwise.

Example:

```
xxppp = 1;  // by = I mean that it should return that value when given to the function
xxxp = 0;
nnnpppz = 0;
npz = 1;
npp = 1;
llleeeegggg = 1;
```

I have tried this:

```
int CheckOcc(char seq[]) {
    int j = 0, counter = 0;

    if (strlen(seq) == 0)
        return 100;  //last is always shorter than nothing

    for (j = 0; j < strlen(seq); j++)
        if (seq[0] == seq[j])
            counter++;

    if (counter <= CheckOcc(seq + j))
        return counter;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

But I just can't get it to work, can anyone give a suggestion please? I have been over this for two hours and just can't figure it out.

EDIT:

Please note that by passing seq + j, I'm actually passing the stirng starting from the first substring after the one that has just ended. The pointer algebra is correct, I just can't figure out the algorithm, in particular, I do not know what to **return**. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Sorry @chux, I wrote count instead of counter while I was deleting the useless part. Fixed it now. The code provides strings directly from main into CheckOcc(), they are valid, the algorithm just doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm do you want `CheckOcc(seq + counter)`?

Comment: I want CheckOcc to return 1 (or any positive value), given a string, if the string is made up of substrings of the same character that are never longer than the one directly after. 0 otherwise. Please see the examples it's hard to explain. Please also take for granted that strings are correct. seq + counter is to compare the count from the first sequence to the count from the second one and so on. j points to where the sequence stops and a new one begins, through pointer algebra. It's the best I came up with..

Comment: `npz = 1;` Why is true?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Because there is no sequence shorter than the one right before it.
n = sequence of lenght one. Is it shorter or equal to the next? (p, lenght 1). Yes, so going on this way, it returns 1.

Comment: Well, @chux has already told you one of your errors, and you'll find the other once you spend a moment to think what the return value of your function is intended to signify.

Comment: @chux I'm very sorry I didn't get your comment sooner, I associated seq + counter with seq + j, since j is a "counter". Now it's clear. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int CheckOcc(char seq[]) {
    int j = 0, counter = 0;

    if (!*seq) return INT_MAX;

    for (j = 0; seq[j] && *seq == seq[j]; j++)
        counter++;

    return (counter <= CheckOcc(seq + j)) ? counter : 0;
}
int main(void){
    char input[128];
    while(1 == scanf("%127[^\n]%*c", input)){
        if(CheckOcc(input))
            printf("%s = 1\n", input);
        else
            printf("%s = 0\n", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your example does indeed work, thanks, you're really really smart. By looking at it though, I see my own thought process, I can't see the difference. I used my own main function for your demo too, so that's not the issue. What did I do wrong? EDIT- Another comment helped me find out. I was incrementing j too much, I should have put another condition in the for loop, thank you so much sir.